# Specifying source IP address for a host route

Tags: linux, routes

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I assigned two IP addresses to the ethernet card by editing /etc/network/interfaces. It now looks like that (skipping lines not related to the question).

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.60.23
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.60.1
    up route add 192.168.60.1 dev eth0
    up route add 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
    up route add 192.168.60.151 gw 10.0.1.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.60.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Now, howerver, I would like to let the packets going to 192.168.60.151 leave my machine with the second IP address (192.168.60.101) as source address.

I tried adding src 192.168.60.101 to the corresponding `up route` line but it didn't work. I also tried to move this line to the eth0:1 block but it didn't work either. When I execute `ip route get 192.168.60.151` I always get `192.168.60.151 via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.60.21`.

I googled but didn't find out how to modify the source address of outgoing packets.

Comment: This question would be better suited on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Ok, I asked the question on serverfault.com [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/525899/specifying-source-ip-address-for-a-host-route).